# Read a csv file from Pandas according to a data from another csv file

Tags: python, pandas, csv

In my code at first I read a csv file using pandas and according to a data in the row I open another csv file. When I try to open that file from the below code an error is shown.

```
in=pd.read_csv("in.csv")
out=pd.read_csv(in.at[0,'id']+".csv")

file=pd.read_csv("input.csv")
file.head()
```

[image]

So I have few more csv files and now I want to open the relevant csv file according to the **id** from **in.csn** file.

When I try to use the above code an error is shown,

```
TypeError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('<U21') dtype('<U21') dtype('<U21')
```

Comment: Please don't post images of code, data, or Tracebacks. Copy and paste it as text then format it as code (select it and type `ctrl-k`) ...
[Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Comment: When asking questions for code that relies on data, it is important that a minimal example of the data is included in your question.  The easier you make it for *us* to copy and paste from your question (so that we can execute your code and test our solution) the more likely you'll get responses. - Please read [mre].

Comment: When posting a question about code that produces an Exception, always include the complete Traceback - copy and paste it then format it as code (select it and type `ctrl-k`). Nothing in your example is using the `add` ufunc.

Comment: It is not best to use keywords such as `in` as variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to convert your id to string because your csv filename should be valid path.

```
out=pd.read_csv(str(in.at[0,'id'])+".csv")
```

will solve your problem. It is not a good practice because it can raise File not found error but you can use it as it is.

Comment: yeah this worked fine, is there any other way to do what I've done here

Comment: If you want to loop over all rows you can use for loop with df.iterrows() or use df.loc to get all ids and loop over them instead of using at for single element. But this is for the looping of course. If you will use just one value then at method is fine.